# Matching a complex data structure (an array of structs) with Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, tdd, bdd

How can I match the following array with Rspec ?

```
[#<struct Competitor html_url="https://github.com/assaf/vanity", description="Experiment Driven Development for Ruby", watchers=845, forks=146>, 
 #<struct Competitor html_url="https://github.com/andrew/split", description="Rack Based AB testing framework", watchers=359, forks=43>]
```

I need to check if a class method return an array of struct like the previous or a more extensive one which include the previous.

**UPDATE:**

I currently have this test which go green,

```
require 'spec_helper'
  describe "Category" do
    before :each do
      @category = Category.find_by(name: "A/B Testing")
    end

    describe ".find_competitors_by_tags" do
      it "returns a list of competitors for category" do
        competitors = Category.find_competitors_by_tags(@category.tags_array).to_s
        competitors.should match /"Experiment Driven Development for Ruby"/
      end
    end
  end
end
```

but I'd like to know if it is the correct way to test the following method or you think it could be better :

```
class Category
  ...

  Object.const_set :Competitor, Struct.new(:html_url, :description, :watchers, :forks)
  def self.find_competitors_by_tags(tags_array)
    competitors = []

    User.all_in('watchlists.tags_array' => tags_array.map{|tag|/^#{tag}/i}).only(:watchlists).each do |u|
      u.watchlists.all_in(:tags_array => tags_array.map{|tag|/^#{tag}/i}).desc(:watchers).each do |wl|
        competitors << Competitor.new(wl.html_url, wl.description, wl.watchers, wl.forks)
      end
    end
    return competitors
  end
end
```

Comment: Could you explain more in detail?

Comment: @Jason Waldrip ... see UPDATE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would test the minimum needed to make sure that your find function works correctly.  You probably don't need to check every field for the returned records for that.  What you have does that.  I'd modify it a bit, to just look at the description (or whatever other field is appropriate):

```
  it "returns a list of competitors for category" do
    competitors = Category.find_competitors_by_tags(@category.tags_array)
    descriptions = competitors.map(&:description).sort
    descriptions.should == [
      "Experiment Driven Development for Ruby",
      "Rack Based AB testing framework",
    ]
  end
```

Comment: seems good, but actually fails because of "exact match expectation":   see http://pastie.org/4161632

Comment: @Luca, Why would you not want to test that the result included exactly the records you expect, no more and no less?